# jquery.load with div as variable

Tags: jquery, function, load

I would like to use jQuery's load function.

I can write:

```
$('#somediv').load('somefile.html #aSpecificDivinThatPage');
```

Now I would like to have a variable as the source div in the html page, how do I write that out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use normal string concatentation:

```
var div = '#aSpecificDivinThatPage';
$('#somediv').load('somefile.html ' + div);
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to copy the html from the source div and put it into another div?

```
$("#destinationDiv").html($("#sourceDiv").html());
```

Comment: the content of the filling for the div is in another html page... i can include it on the same page, but that not the question!